# PHP Warning: mail(): SMTP server response: 501 Must specify to address &lt;address&gt;

Tags: php, smtp, sendmail, email

Cannot understand why I am getting this error - both to & from email addresses are valid (I use them daily) so cannot figure out how this is happening - any help would be appreciated.

NOTE: This is working in production but is throwing errors in dev. I have stricter config in dev. NOTE: I am testing locally on PC using smtp4dev

```
$to = 'recipient <myemail@mydomain.com.au>';
$cc = 'copy <myemail@mydomain.com.au>';
$from = 'sender <myemail@mydomain.com.au>';
$filename = 'Invoice#'.$order_id.'.pdf';
$message = file_get_contents(ROOT_DIR.'admin/include/email-body.html');
$content = chunk_split(base64_encode($pdf_file));
$uid = md5(uniqid(time()));

$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'To: '. $to . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Cc: '. $cc . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: '. $from . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"".$uid."\"\r\n\r\n";
$headers .= "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\r\n";
$headers .= "--".$uid."\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n\r\n";
$headers .= $message."\r\n\r\n";
$headers .= "--".$uid."\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: application/pdf; name=\"".$filename."\"\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$filename."\"\r\n\r\n";
$headers .= $content."\r\n\r\n";
$headers .= "--".$uid."--";

if (mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)) {
  print "SUCCESS";
} else {
  print "FALIED";
}
```

Here is the result if I print the variables on the mail() line:

```
mail(recipient <myemail@mydomain.com.au>, Company - Invoice#12451, "",
MIME-Version: 1.0 
To: recipient <myemail@mydomain.com.au> 
Cc: copy <myemail@mydomain.com.au> 
From: sender <myemail@mydomain.com.au> 
Content-Type: multipart/mixed;
boundary="2c88ff549e67c83e7a6e3df0bffe9dc9"

This is a multi-part message in MIME format.
--2c88ff549e67c83e7a6e3df0bffe9dc9 Content-type:text/html;
charset=iso-8859-1 Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

---> html message body stripped <---


--2c88ff549e67c83e7a6e3df0bffe9dc9 Content-Type: application/pdf;
name="Invoice#12451.pdf" Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="Invoice#12451.pdf"

--> pdf attachment stripped <--


--2c88ff549e67c83e7a6e3df0bffe9dc9--)
```

Comment: This might get better answers on StackOverflow, but shouldn't `$message` contain everything from `This is a multi-part message in MIME format.` onwards? You've got the whole message, including the body, in the headers.

Comment: thanks - I've got it on stack overflow but because the message was SMTP related I thought someone in here might know common causes

Answer (score 1):

Your $to must be only the mail address. The SMTP dialog expects a mail address in angle brackets and you are feeding it the contents of the To: header. The same for $from too.